# Is it possible to set the browser opened by a hyperlink in an email?

Tags: email

Currently I have wrote a program to send an email that contains a hyperlink to users. But I want to restrict users from opening it using internet explorer, is it possible to control from my side that it restricts IE? Or does it always follow the default browser set by the users side?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Program in what language/script?
And what if the user has no other browser installed than IE?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add, the email is written in html and the program is java. For this case please just consider that the user has other browsers installed.